# Ctrl+f5 clear session values

Tags: php, ctrl

I have a chat system in my site.

When i press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> buttons the chat will be refeshed with online and offline members and it will logout the page and display the login page.

Can I clear session values by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> buttons?

Comment: What? I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is loosing you cookies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're referring to is a hard-refresh, which clears your cache and forces resources to be downloaded again. Doing a hard refresh doesn't destroy session variables. Destroying a session destroys session variables.